# Is there an inexpensive way to decompose a video into frames and apply a snapchat-like filter to each frame?

Tags: post-production, filter

I have a friend who has been taking stop-motion pictures, applying a snapchat "art" filter to each picture, then composing them into video (with pretty awesome results). He is interested in mechanically applying filters like that to video. I assume this is relatively trivial in high end (meaning expensive) video or photo editing software. Is there an inexpensive way to do this, say using the Gimp or a similar free/cheap editing software?

Answer (score 1):

Most motion graphics applications can import most video types and apply filters to them. I believe that [Adobe After Effects](https://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) is available for a subscription (so cheap if you use it only for a month), and [Apple's Motion](http://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/motion/) is available for $49 from the Mac App Store.

Or if that's too much, I believe that [iMovie](http://www.apple.com/imovie/) is only $15 and has a number of simple snapchat-like filters available.